# how to show images from ftp folder with folder names and images names in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am beginner in asp.net development. I am creating an web application where I am required to show images from folder along with folder name. Such that **one list containing folder names when one folder name is selected its file names are displayed (images names) and also in image viewer images are displayed one by one on button click. then so on for next folders.** 
*Any suggestion, code or useful link will be highly appreciated.* 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

You can use Jquery tree view with Asp.net

http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php

For jquery try this

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Comment: I am facing difficulty using listviews. I've listview and i am using select button link along with each row.. now i've string array of say application numbers and i want two columns in my listview, 1st is select button column and 2nd is application number. I am not getting how to display that. earlier i was binding it but now i want to bind it to only that column because it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

Check this ready to use control with lesser effort I suppose. http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/FileManager/

Comment: thanx alot. this is new thing for me and really interesting @Amit i've done it using list views :) but now the remaining work is to display images on image viewer. I'll post if I face any difficulty regarding that.